# How to grant SQL Agent proxy to a public role in MSSQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, role

I want to grant SQL Agent proxy to a public role in msdb database in MSSQL 2014.

I have the following query and I want this to return me some valid output.

```
USE [msdb] 
SELECT 
 sp.name AS proxyname 
FROM dbo.sysproxylogin spl 
JOIN sys.database_principals dp 
  ON dp.sid = spl.sid 
JOIN sysproxies sp 
 ON sp.proxy_id = spl.proxy_id 
WHERE principal_id = USER_ID('public');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer your question I want to draw your attention about granting permissions to Public Msdb Role on the Proxy.

Reference: [Best Practices in Configuring SQL Server Agent Proxy account.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2160741/best-practices-in-configuring-sql-server-agent-proxy-account)

> Proper care must be taken when granting permissions to a security
>   principal on a Proxy **especially when granting permissions to Public
>   Msdb Role on the Proxy. Every user in the database is a member of the
>   public role and as a result every user gains access to the Proxy when
>   Public Msdb role is granted access to the Proxy.** You can query the
>   sysproxylogin system table to get the list of SQL Server logins that
>   are associated with each SQL Server Agent proxy account.

You can achieve this by using the following TSQL (assuming your proxy is created properly).

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  

EXEC dbo.sp_grant_login_to_proxy  
    @msdb_role = N'public',  
    @proxy_name = N'Proxy Name' ;  
GO
```

[Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-grant-login-to-proxy-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) about using `sp_grant_login_to_proxy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Yes, I am aware about the security issues and I wanted to test only that.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it satisfied your question.  That way other readers can take advantage.